# Xcode - How to take screenshot for camera View Controller using Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

My application have an Camera View Controller and I need to take **screenshot** of this view for **iTunesConnect**.

I have all physical devices but don't have iPhone Plus.

Is there any workaround for taking screenshot of camera view with live camera using Simulator?

Comment: The simulator doesn't support the camera, You need the real device.

Comment: You can just Photoshop this or using the Preview App on the Mac.